# How to speed up the process of setting up a GDB debugger breakpoint at a popular header file?

Tags: gdb

Hi I have been using GDB debugger, and I recently find out that when I set up a breakpoint at some popular header file, the GDB debugger takes a long time to process such request.

The GDB command I use is: "break source_file.h:429".

Is there any method to speed up without changing the source code?

Comment: "Is there ..." -- maybe. Please update your question with versions of GDB and the compiler used, as well as the compilation flags.